# Maximum virtual memory and physical memory

Tags: memory, operating-systems

A Intel 64-bit x86 CPU,four-level hierarchical page table.Each for levels of page table can contain 512 entries, and the page size is 4KB. What's the maximum size for virtual memory and physical memory?

I think the maximum virtual memory should be 2^48 in that 9 bits for referencing the position of page table and there are 4 page tables. Thus 4*9+12=48(4KB offset). But I am not sure how to calculate the maximum physical memory. Or it just cannot tell from this information?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting theoretical question.

First, let's be clear: Intel's 64-bit architecture is actually AMDs 64-bit extensions to Intel's 32-bit architecture. That's the origin of the very technical term of `x86_64`. So are you asking about "Intel"-specific CPUs, or about the x86_64 architecture in general? Second, are you writing or editing the Wikipedia article on this entry? If so, we should avoid using Wikipedia to help find the answer :)

Why wouldn't the theoretical maximum virtual memory size be bounded by the 64-bit word-length of the address pointers? According to the wikipedia article, "AMD decided only the least 48-bits would be used". Future versions of the architecture allow this to be extended. So really, the "theoretical maximum" *could be* 2^64. So now we're talking about something less than theoretical.

The x86_64 "long mode" of addressing allows for *2 MB pages*, ie, 2^21 not only 4KB (2^12) pages, a difference of 2^9, so I get (from your calculations) 2^57. But that's more than the architecture currently allows, so it's still "only" 2^48.

For physical memory, again from Wikipedia, "Current AMD64 implementations support a physical address space of up to 2^48 bytes of RAM". OK, but maybe there are other bounds imposed elsewhere. On the very low end, we have the motherboard manufacturer which typically set this based on the number of slots. Somehwere in the middle, we have the memory controller, which nowadays are actually integrated into the CPU (but not always, and not necessarily -- so again, how theoretical is this question). The memory controllers will also limit the address space or the number of possible chips they control.

Comment: What's the down vote for?

Comment: I think i have a troll  / stalker. @jao